# How do I override up button behavior in search view

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I've implemented searchView like YouTube app does in separate fragment. So when user clicks search icon new fragment launched with expanded search view.

Now if now one clicks up button then search view is collapsed. And only if one clicks up button again then previous fragment appears from back stack.

What I need to do is when user clicks up button from expanded search view state then the search fragment is closed immediately and previous fragment appears.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've found solution that almost works:

```
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onMenuItemActionCollapse");
            onBackPressed();
            return true;  // Return true to collapse action view
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when expanded
            return true;  // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });
```

But this solution has one BIG issue: if one press back arrow button when there is text in the search view text field then

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SearchFragment not attached to Activity* is thrown.

Why this exception happens and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Override onOptionsItemSelected() in your activity/fragment. The up button had and id "android.R.id.home"

```
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //Handle Up button
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    @Override    
    public boolean onClose() {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // Or other mechanism, depends on what you have.
        return false; // Don't consume event, will dismiss search.
    }
});
```